# jQuery click trigger disable move page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 radios with labels, when a user clicks on one of those, the change event is active.

```
$('input[type=radio][name=cs_radio_province]').change(function() {
  //Do something
}
```

Now, I make it automatic select in radio with `prop`

```
$('#button').click(function (){
    $('input#radio1').prop('checked', true);
})
```

But change event is not call in this case, so I use trigger click instead.

```
$('#button').click(function (){
    $('input#radio1').click();
})
```

Now change event for radios button is working, I put my radios at the bottom of the page and I am scrolling to the top, when `$('input#radio1').click();` running, my position always at the bottom near radio buttons.

So how do I fix that? I don't want my browser scroll down when click trigger active or any better idea?

Comment: Have you tested `$('input#radio1').change();`? As you are binding change event, why not trigger it.

Comment: Use `.change()`, not `.click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should trigger `change` event.

```
$('#button').click(function (){
    $('#radio1').prop('checked', true).change();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select any radio button via below code :

```
$("#radio2").attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Please format your code and add little explanation for future visitors.